# How to use custom field to add class to a post?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to add another class to `<div class="postthumbnail">`. I wanted to style one post different. Therefore, after researching, I found that the best method is to use custom field to add class to the post.

This tutorial, [How to style WP posts different](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-each-wordpress-post-differently/), especially this section at bottom, explained how I can add class to the post using the custom field. I did so by giving the custom field a name "en_proceso_class" and the value, "en_proceso" which is an css class. But I'm confused by the last two codes I need to add. The tutorial wasn't clear on where I need to add them.

My original code is:

```
        <?php
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=9&posts_per_page=9&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>

<div class="proyectpost">
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="innerpost">

             <div class="postthumbnail">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full' );
     echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%"  />';
    } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="posttitle">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <span><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true); ?></span>
            </div><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="postsubtitle">
        <div class="datepanel">

        </div>
        </div>

</div>
</article><!-- #post-## --> 

</div>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="paginationbar">
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    'show_all'           => True,
    'prev_next'          => False
) );
?>
</div>

<?php 
// clean up after the query and pagination
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is section of the code that I'm trying to add the new code to:

```
<div class="innerpost">

            <?php $custom_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'en_proceso_class'); ?>

             <div class="postthumbnail <?php en_proceso_class('class-1 class-2 ' . $custom_variable); ?>">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full' );
     echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%"  />';
    } ?>
            </div>
```

What do I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part isn't 100% clear but I'll try to answer as best I can.

This piece of code:

```
$custom_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'en_proceso_class');
```

Gets the value of a post meta field name: 'en_proceso_class'. You actually need to set that first in order for this to work. And you need to add 'true' as another parameter to that function. See here for more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Then there's this:

```
div class="postthumbnail <?php en_proceso_class('class-1 class-2 ' . $custom_variable); ?>">
```

Which calls a function named 'en_proceso_class' -- I don't think this is what you want to do. Unless you declared that function beforehand you'll to do something like:

```
div class="postthumbnail <?php echo 'class-1 class-2 ' . $custom_variable; ?>">
```

So the whole code put together would look like this:

```
<div class="innerpost">
    <?php 
        // Get post meta that is already set
        $custom_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'en_proceso_class', true); 
    ?> 

     <div class="postthumbnail <?php echo 'class-1 class-2 ' . $custom_values; ?>">
        <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full' );
                echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%"  />';
            } 
        ?>
</div>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! It works! What I dislike about some tutorials and wordpress documentation are that they just provide the code and are vague about where it's suppose to go. I need to see the actual code to understand what I need to do...

Comment: No problem ;) Glad I could help

Comment: Ummm... Do you know meta box in wordpress? I'm looking into converting this code into a meta box checkbox but I couldn't figure out how I can use the meta box and what is the name and value of the checkbox. What I'm trying to do is to make it user-friendly for a client and thus, if he's on a new post and wanted to style it different, I want him to click on the checkbox. I don't want him to change the value in any way.

Comment: Hey, check this out: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box in the example at the middle of the page they show you how to create a meta box, add field and save it.

Comment: Thanks! I already got it working thanks to the tutorial: http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/